# Proving $f(x)\leq x$ with some conditions

Tags: calculus, functions, inequality

Let $f:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ be a function such that

- $f(1)=1$
- $f(x)+f(y)\leq f(x+y)$, for any numbers $x$ , $y$ , $x+y \in [0,1]$

Then we have to show that $f(x)\leq x$ for any $x\in [0,1]$.

I can see that $f(0)=0$, and am able to get a few more properties but am unable to prove this, please help.

Comment: You are unable to prove this because there exist counterexamples.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I suspected so. Please give them.

Comment: You tagged it with calculus. Is the function continuous or differentiate?

Comment: It is true for rational points but not necessarily true for irrational points.

Comment: @CalvinLin No, there is no such condition. I tagged it because you can use tools of calculus, whether they apply or not.

Comment: @CalvinLin Is it so? Please give the proof for rationals as answer along with the counter-proof for irrationals, and I will accept it.

Comment: See also my  answer to [another question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/778624/determine-the-smallest-number-p).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the function $f\colon[0,1]\to[0,1]$
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}0&\text{if }0\le x\le\frac12\\
1&\text{if }\frac12<x\le 1
\end{cases} $$
One verifies that it satisfies the condition and that $f(x)=1$ for $x>\frac12$, hence any inequality of the form "$f(x)\le Cx$ for all $x\in[0,1]$" can only hold if $C\ge 2$.

Comment: Nice. Do there exist counterexamples for $C\ge2$?

Answer (score 1):

$f$ is monotone: $0\leq x\lt y \leq 1$ then  $f(x)\leq f (y )$.

so, if  $0\leq x\leq \dfrac1n$, then $nf(x)\leq f(nx)\leq f(1)=1$, so $f(x)\leq \dfrac1n$

1). $f(x)\leq x $ is not true, for

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}0&0\le x\le \frac12\\
1&\frac12<x\le 1
\end{cases}$$

3). **If It is true for rational points**, that is $x\in\Bbb Q\Rightarrow f(x)\leq x$, then

$$f(x)\leq x, \qquad  x\in [0,1]$$

In fact, if $0\lt x\lt1$, we can choose $r_1>r_2>\dotsb\gt x$ such that $r_n\in\Bbb Q$ and $\lim r_n=x$, then

$$f(x)\leq f(r_n)\leq r_n$$

Let $n\to\infty$, we get $f(x)\leq x $

Comment: Umm..why do you state contradicting results in both answer..I don't quite understand.

Comment: No contradicting results

Comment: Simple counterexample :)